# Picasso doesn't load in Android

Tags: android, picasso

I put the .jar file inside the /libs folder and added it as library, now my build.gradle file has these dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':SmoothProgressBar')
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

My manifest is like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prova" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But when i need to load an image it doesen't do anything and no error come from logcat. Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ImageView img;

private String image = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOb1t.png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    Picasso.with(this).setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(this).load(Uri.parse(image)).into(img);
    }

}
```

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Eclipse worked fine without any problem.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.enrico.prova"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
}
```

EDIT2:
Logcat:

```
02-23 16:41:36.857  28865-28865/com.example.enrico.prova D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R1] Request{http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png}
02-23 16:41:36.858  28865-28884/com.example.enrico.prova D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R1]+0ms
02-23 16:41:36.876  28865-29238/com.example.enrico.prova D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R1]+16ms
02-23 16:41:36.883  28865-28884/com.example.enrico.prova D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R1]+25ms for error
02-23 16:41:37.112  28865-28884/com.example.enrico.prova D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R1]+254ms
02-23 16:41:37.112  28865-28865/com.example.enrico.prova D/Picasso﹕ Main        errored      [R1]+255ms
```

Comment: Check this https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/adding-picasso-in-android-studio

Comment: Tried it, not working

Comment: please poste your 'build.gradle'

Comment: define a placeholder and an error image and see if it is working. Also enable logging and check your logcat.

Comment: I wrote what logcat says

Comment: The Image you are trying to download is 2560 × 1600. This is not related to the issue, but you will run into OOM `Exceptions` if you do not crop it. Picasso allows you to easily do so.

Comment: I tried with another image: http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png
Still doesen't work.

Comment: I guess it is because of the two "//" inside the url. Maybe you try it with a a better URL?

Comment: Tried with this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LOb1t.png, not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your permissions inside the `<application>`. They should go inside the `<manifest>` outside `<application>`.

Answer (score 1):

hello please try since you have to pass a uri to the Picasso load

```
load(Uri.parse(image))
```

Can you please post update code..with Uri.parse..because as you can see it works in a project of mine

[image]

Comment: I updated the question adn tried to use this image you posted.
Not working

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with Maven Central instead of jar like,

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':SmoothProgressBar')
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

and may be instead `getApplicationContext()` , you should use just `this`.

Comment: Done that:
private String image = "http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png";
Picasso.with(this).load(Uri.parse(image)).into(img);
Not working.

I added my gradle file

Comment: shouldn't your image path be "http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2014/images/example_image.png"

Answer (score 0):

OK, this sounds super obvious but was my issue...Does your phone have internet? Is it connected? Just test if all else fails as sometimes it's the simple things that we overlook.